# Game or gamified application for teaching/learning secondary school mathematics

Tags: secondary-education, technology-in-education, interactive-teaching, games

Is there any game or gamified application for teaching/learning mathematics covering a **high school/secondary school** curriculum?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is one major goal of [Expii](https://www.expii.com/), a crowd-sourced work in progress.

Here are some other related projects I've seen:

- Alcumus from the Art of Problem Solving (AoPS): http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Alcumus/index.php
- Brilliant: http://brilliant.org/
- Clever Math: https://www.clevermath.org/
- Curriki: http://www.curriki.org/
- DragonBox App: http://www.dragonboxapp.com/
- Euclid: The Game: http://euclidthegame.com/Tutorial/
- Established MOOCs like Khan Academy, Coursera, edX, etc.
- Oppia: https://www.oppia.org/
- Terry Tao's linear equation games: http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/04/18/new-version-of-algebra-game/

From what I can tell, Khan Academy currently seems like the "most comprehensive" answer to your question, but I don't know if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Many of these are interesting. I don't understand how Khan academy is a "gamification". Am I missing something?

Comment: @JonBannon Have you seen their interactive exercises?  You get points!

Comment: That said, I only qualified these as "related" projects since the amount of gamification in each varies quite a bit. For instance, DragonBox, Euclid: The Game, and Terry Tao's game are much more interactive than Khan Academy, but of course much more specialized too.